# Cannot create template<typename T> vector<T>::iterator in c++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

```
template<typename T>
bool Palindrome(vector<T> word) {
vector<T>::iterator start = word.begin();
vector<T>::iterator end = word.end();
for (;start != (word.begin() + word.end())/ 2;start++) {
    if (*start != *(--end)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

I cannot create iterator of as in line 3 of code. I have to make a palindrome checker for any data type. Is there problem regarding the syntax or we cannot do it this way. Thanks!

The error message is as follows:

'end' was not declared in this scope
'start' was not declared in this scope
dependent-name 'std::vector::iterator' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
dependent-name 'std::vector::iterator' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
expected ';' before 'end'
expected ';' before 'start'
need 'typename' before 'std::vector::iterator' because 'std::vector' is a dependent scope
need 'typename' before 'std::vector::iterator' because 'std::vector' is a dependent scope
no match for 'operator/' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >' and 'int')

Comment: look for dependent names.

Comment: And honestly, if you're doing a palindrome checker, you need to be using `rbegin()` as well as `begin()`.

Comment: What is the purpose of magic number '6' in a generic palindrome checker?

Comment: @Arun sorry, edited it

Comment: P.S. You should post the error message as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
template<typename T>
bool Palindrome( const std::vector<T> &word ) 
{
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator start = word.begin();
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end   = word.end();

    for ( ; start < word.begin() + word.size() / 2; ++start ) 
    {
        if ( *start != *--end ) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is a test

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
bool Palindrome( const std::vector<T> &word ) 
{
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator start = word.begin();
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end   = word.end();

    for ( ; start < word.begin() + word.size() / 2; ++start ) 
    {
        if ( *start != *--end ) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 1 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Palindrome( v ) << std::endl;

    v = { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Palindrome( v ) << std::endl;

    v = { 1, 2, 2, 1 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Palindrome( v ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `typename`

```
typename vector<T>::iterator start = word.begin();
```